# When I try to run an AVD on sndroid studio I get an error massege

Tags: android-studio, haxm

Every time I try to run AVD this error apears: "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. HAXM is not installed.  Install Intel HAXM for better emulation performance" I tried to uninstall and reinstall it but it doesn't work. do you knoe why??

I try to uninstall and reinstall ut it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio **Settings->Appearance and Behavior->System Setting->Android Sdk**

[image]

Keep in mind this just downloads the Intel HAXM.